# Alfresco: does community edition provides document library functions

Tags: alfresco, ecm

I have installed free Alfresco community edition and try to figure out what content management abilities are ready to me out-of-the-box.

I noticed I can create spaces and put content there, there is version control and some basic workflows but can I:

- Structurize content with folders?
- Apply filters while browsing content list?

All demos I have seen appeals to Alfresco Share, but does share is inside comminity edition or is it just another product that is not free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share is/should also be automatically be installed, if you replace your url which ends on alfresco to share do you get a login screen?

Within Share you can set Tags, and with tags you can filter content....

In Alfresco Explorer you can use Categories. If you click on edit details there is a panel below where you can add categories.
You can see this article/book for some screenshots:
https://www.packtpub.com/article/implementing-document-management-alfresco-3-2

---

You can check the share-config-custom.xml somewhere in web-extension folder.

There should be something like this written:

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Remote">
        <remote>
            <endpoint>
                <id>alfresco-noauth</id>
                <name>Alfresco - unauthenticated access</name>
                <description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that do not require authentication</description>
                <connector-id>alfresco</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
                <identity>none</identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint>
                <id>alfresco</id>
                <name>Alfresco - user access</name>
                <description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that require user authentication</description>
                <connector-id>alfresco</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
                <identity>user</identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint>
                <id>alfresco-feed</id>
                <name>Alfresco Feed</name>
                <description>Alfresco Feed - supports basic HTTP authentication via the EndPointProxyServlet</description>
                <connector-id>http</connector-id>
                <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
                <basic-auth>true</basic-auth>
                <identity>user</identity>
            </endpoint>
        </remote>
    </config>
```

I you check that the localhost points towards the right Alfresco installation, then it should be fine. If not put the ip in, were Alfresco is running. It could be that Share isn't connecting to Alfresco. Present the log files alfresco.log probably if it isn't working.

Comment: Thank you, @Shazada! That's great, but what is the account I should use for Share admin as default after installation? admin/admin works greate for /alfresco but not for /share

Comment: That's true! Admin managed to disorder configuration file somehow with localization, not it's fixed!